# Swift: Get subpaths in path and files in subpaths?

Tags: ios, swift, bundle

My app has this sort of file structure for the sounds in it:

[image]

A "Sound" folder with a bunch of numbered subfolders, such as "1", "2", "3" and so on.

The problem is, I have no clue how to find the folder "1", let alone the files in it. I tried this:

```
for path in Bundle.main.paths(forResourcesOfType: "wav", inDirectory: "Sound") {
  print(path)
}
```

At no point does this print "Test.wav", or "1".

Any help would be fantastic!

**EDIT:** If I set the path to "", then it prints the folder "1". However, it also prints all the wav files. What is the type for a folder supposed to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would get the path to the `Sound` folder and then use `FileManager` to get the contents of the `Sound` folder.

```
if let soundURL = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Sound", withExtension: nil) {
    let urls = FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: soundURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [ .skipsHiddenFiles ]) {
        // iterate the list of URLs as needed
    }
}
```

I leave it as an exercise to deal with exception handling.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but what is FileManager? I've never seen it anywhere yet. What's the difference of that compared to Bundle?

Comment: See the reference documentation.

Comment: I forgot to mention, there are a few other wav files in the "Sound" folder, not just directories. So sorry to annoy you again, but is there any way to ONLY get subdirectories in a directory, not files as well?

Comment: Ignore what you don't need as you iterate `urls`.

Comment: Isn't this functionally the same as doing `for path in Bundle.main.paths(forResourcesOfType: nil, inDirectory: "Sound") {`?

Comment: They are different. Your code gets a list of files (as path strings) directly inside the "Sound" folder. The code I posted gives you a full recursive listing of files (as URLs) of the "Sound" folder.

Comment: So does this: `for url in Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: nil, subdirectory: "Sound")! {` sorry for being annoying, I just feel like it's pretty dodgy looping through unneeded things

Comment: Again, no. The `Bundle` methods are not recursive. The `FileManager` code I posted is.